# Proving a function is injective and surjective

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

**Question:**

Consider  $ f : \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ via  $ \ f(n) = n + (-1)^{n+1}$

Is $ f$ injective? Justify your answer.
Is $f$ surjective? Justify your answer.

**My attempt:**

If $n$ is even then $ f(n) = n - 1$ and if $n$ is odd then $ f(n) = n + 1$. In either case $f$ is injective because $ f(a) = f(b) \implies a = b$ for $ a,b \in \mathbb{N}$.

I am not sure how to prove it is surjective.

Comment: maybe try to do cases even and odd for surjective

Comment: Have I proven correctly that it is injective?

Comment: Is there $x$ such that $f (x)=0$

Comment: @ Salahamam_ Fatima How can $f(x) = 0$? Don't natural numbers start at $1$

Comment: injective looks fine to me... but are you convinced that you've proved it?

Comment: @JoshMitkitzel zero is not natural.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have:

$$f(2\mathbb{N})=2\mathbb{N}+1$$

and

$$f(2\mathbb{N}+1)=2\mathbb{N}$$

so it is surjective.

Note: $f(A)$ is the image of the set $A$ throught $f$

---

- $f(2\mathbb{N})=2\mathbb{N}+1 \space$ because $f(2n)=2n-1$
- $f(2\mathbb{N}+1)=2\mathbb{N} \space$ because $f(2n+1)=2n+2$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $n$ is even. The function either adds or subtracts $1$to its input, so consider $n+1$ and $n-1$.

These are both odd, so which one would give $n$ after being passed through $f$?

You have shown that for any even number $n$, there exists an input $a$ that makes $f(a)=n$. This is the definition of surjectivity - there exists an input that gives every possible (even ) number.

Now do the same thing for odd numbers, and you are done.

(Don't forget to check edge cases like $0$, if you are including it in $\mathbb{N}$.)